# Browsers unable to get internet while other applications can

Tags: windows, networking

IE and Chrome are both currently unable to connect to the internet.  Games, Google Talk, etc. are connected just fine.  I've tried using `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` to no avail.  Windows of course couldn't diagnose the issue either...

Any suggestions on what I should look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into ie options check there is no proxy set up? Turn off anti virus and firewall tempary to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Make sure to try unchecking the "Automatically detect settings" for Proxy settings in Connection -> LAN in Internet Options.

Answer (score 0):

Check for proxy settings in the browsers.  Particular IE because its proxy settings can affect other things.

Download a couple malware scanners like Malware Bytes and AVG Free and run a quick scan.  Then a full scan overnight if nothing is found.  Some malware will cause connection problems.

Check your hosts file for bad entries.  Malware will sometimes put entries there that would cause redirect your browser requests to some other address.

Also try to run a command like `ping google.com`.  If it gets a response then it's probably not a host file issue, but could still be a browser setting issue like a bad proxy.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes caused by some data in your cache.  Clear out the cache in each of the browsers.

Comment: respectfully disagree